# help in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have a table that has id,fromdate and todate as columns.
i need to select the ids that is between 2dates specified by the user. for example:

```
ID   FromDate   ToDate
1    2010-01-10 2010-01-13
2    2009-03-20 2010-01-09
```

so if the user entered datefrom=`2000-00-00` and dateto=`2009-03-21`
i return :

```
ID
2
```

if the user entered from=`2009-00-00` to=`2011-00-00`
i return :

```
ID
1
2
```

note i am using MS server 2008

Comment: Do you want to return rows fully or partially inside the range, or only fully inside?

Comment: i tried George's way but it doesn't give correct results...

Comment: Can you describe what are the results ?

Comment: If you need to include also the boundary dates you have to replace the > and < operators with >= and <=.

Comment: your examples are strange, there is no valid date with a month of zero and a day of zero.  also, can you clarify  if both FromDate and ToDate in the table have to be between the given datefrom and dateto?  in the first example this is not the case.

Comment: i need to include dates in between for example:
    id     FromDate        ToDate
    1      2010-01-10   2010-01-20

if the user entered FromDate=2010-01-12 and todate=2010-01-15
id=1 should still be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
--needed for each query run
DECLARE @YourTable  table     (RowID int, FromDate datetime, ToDate datetime)
DECLARE @datefrom  datetime
       ,@dateto    datetime

INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (1,'2010-01-10', '2010-01-13')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (2,'2009-03-20', '2010-01-09')
```

first example

```
--be sure to use the DECLAREs and INSERTs from above with this
SELECT @datefrom='2000-01-01'
      ,@dateto='2009-03-21'

--query to that only checks if the FromDate is between the given @datefrom and @dateto, which is necessary for the OPs first example
SELECT 
    *
    FROM @YourTable
    WHERE FromDate>=@datefrom AND FromDate<@dateto+1
```

OUTPUT:

```
RowID       FromDate                ToDate
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2           2009-03-20 00:00:00.000 2010-01-09 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)
```

second example

```
--same query as above, but run with example two dates
--be sure to use the DECLAREs and INSERTs from above with this
SELECT @datefrom='2009-01-01'
      ,@dateto='2011-01-01'

SELECT 
    *
    FROM @YourTable
    WHERE FromDate>=@datefrom AND FromDate<@dateto+1
```

OUTPUT:

```
RowID       FromDate                ToDate
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1           2010-01-10 00:00:00.000 2010-01-13 00:00:00.000
2           2009-03-20 00:00:00.000 2010-01-09 00:00:00.000

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Alternate queries, to make sure that the entire FromDate+ToDate range is within the given @datefrom and @dateto values use this query:

```
--be sure to use the DECLAREs and INSERTs from above with this    SELECT @datefrom='2009-03-22'
      ,@dateto='2011-01-01'

SELECT 
    *
    FROM @YourTable
    WHERE FromDate>=@datefrom AND ToDate<@dateto+1
```

OUTPUT:

```
RowID       FromDate                ToDate
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1           2010-01-10 00:00:00.000 2010-01-13 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE FromData>@startdate AND ToData<@enddate
```